# Localize Hololens in mapped space between application runs (wihout anchors)

Tags: hololens

Please is it possible to localize Hololens in specific map between application runs without using anchors? I would like to use coordinate system provided by `SpatialStationaryFrameOfReference` as it makes more sense for my use-case than anchors. However this would obviously result in different origin for each application run. Therefore I am looking for a way to get transform from `SpatialStationaryFrameOfReference` -> to absolute position in current map.

For example 3D view in device portal always shows Hololens in correct relation to current map - even when no anchors are placed in it. Therefore I thought it should be possible to do this also from application. So far I have only thought of placing some random anchor that would be then used to get a transform from the anchor’s coordinate system to that of the stationary reference frame (using TryGetTransformTo). I guess this should technically work, but I there might be also a better way, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to set the application's origin is to detect the QR code in the environment and establish a coordinate system. For more information please see:[QR code tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/qr-code-tracking#detecting-qr-codes)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a valid solution, but I would ideally like to use built-in ability to localize Hololens in mapped space (just like it works in device portal's 3D view). Please is there is some other way to do so, or anchors and QR codes are the only ways to go about this?

Comment: What you need is a persistent coordinate system, which can be provided by anchor and QR code. As far as I know, there is no other built-in way that can do it. Besides, the 3D view does not disclose any information about which technique is used as internal realization.

Comment: All right, thank you very much for info. I guess I will use the QR codes then.